# Vector of bytes to quadword

Tags: c++

I have a vector of bytes and i want to convert them into a quadword data type (64bit little endian).

example of vector to Dword (32bit):

```
int DataConversor::toDword()
{
    return ((data[0] << 24) | (data[1] << 16) | (data[2] << 8) | (data[3]));
}
```

Problem is shifting with more than 32 bytes its undefined behaviour according to Visual Studio 2013:

```
__int64 DataConversor::toQuadWord()
{
    return (__int64)((data[0] << 64 | data[1] << 56 | data[2] << 48 | data[3] << 40 |
        data[4] << 32 | data[5] << 24) | (data[6] << 16) | (data[7] << 8) | (data[8]));
}
```

Any method for accomplish this, without using _ASM directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `data[0] << 64` is probably an accident...

But `data[0] << 56` is not what you want. You want `static_cast<uint64_t>(data[0]) << 56`. And then that repeated on all of the other operations as well.

Therefore, you want your function to look something like:

```
int64_t DataConversor::toQuadWord() {
    uint64_t result = 0;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[0]) << 56;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[1]) << 48;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[2]) << 40;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[3]) << 32;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[4]) << 24;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[5]) << 16;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[6]) << 8;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(data[7]) << 0;
    return (int64_t) result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No compiler independant way. You can use `int64_t __builtin_bswap64 (int64_t x)` on GCC and `unsigned __int64 _byteswap_uint64(unsigned __int64 value)` on MSVC to swap the endianess. You could use that, if your array is by definition everywhere a big endian (at least it will not change endianess on other systems). You have to typecast the type to 64bit integer.

```
int64_t convertEndianess(uint8_t x[])
{
    return _byteswap_uint64(*static_cast<int64_t*>(x));
}
```

Comment: If `x` is not 64 bit aligned, some processors will execute invalid code for this. For example, [this processor will](http://www.ti.com/product/tms320c6657).

Answer (score -1):

With little endian and you know the bytes are packed, you can do

```
return *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&data[0]) ;
```

Comment: If `x` is not 64 bit aligned, some processors will execute invalid code for this statement. And you probably meant `int64_t` instead of `int64_6`.